# Double new-line when copy to konsole on xrdp

Tags: linux, terminal, remote-desktop, copy-paste, konsole

at the beginning, sorry for my bad english.
This problem that make me crazy... I have a debian jessie server, and i use to work on it by X11-xrdp, from my win10 machine.
When i copy from windows and paste in konsole (or in any other terminal) on rdp session, i obtain an extra newline per line.
For example, when I paste:

```
echo
echo
echo
```

I obtain

```
root@lismall:~$ echo
enter code here

root@lismall:~$ 
root@lismall:~$ echo

root@lismall:~$ 
root@lismall:~$ echo
```

If I do the same thing in vim, after set ":set list", i see this:

```
echo$
$
echo$
$
echo$
```

If i paste the same lines in a tex editor (medit for example), it's ok, no double newline.

This is my "stty -a" output:

```
speed 38400 baud; rows 48; columns 192; line = 0;
intr = ^C; quit = ^\; erase = ^?; kill = ^U; eof = ^D; eol = <undef>; eol2 = <undef>; swtch = <undef>; start = ^Q; stop = ^S; susp = ^Z; rprnt = ^R; werase = ^W; lnext = ^V; flush = ^O;
min = 1; time = 0;
-parenb -parodd -cmspar cs8 -hupcl -cstopb cread -clocal -crtscts
-ignbrk brkint -ignpar -parmrk -inpck -istrip -inlcr -igncr -icrnl ixon -ixoff -iuclc -ixany imaxbel -iutf8
opost -olcuc -ocrnl onlcr -onocr -onlret -ofill -ofdel nl0 cr0 tab0 bs0 vt0 ff0
isig icanon iexten echo echoe echok -echonl -noflsh -xcase -tostop -echoprt echoctl echoke
```

Could you please help me?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: The reason is that Windows uses a CR LF sequence for end of line, as opposed to the CR in Linux. Your text editor ignores LF, the terminal doesn't. I don't know a good way to change this behaviour; you'd need convert line endings in some cases, but not in others.

Comment: Same problem when I copy from Ubuntu machine and paste on X11-RDP session on debian server, opened with rdesktop...

Comment: Then the question is *what* you copied from the Ubuntu machine - if it was e.g. a DOS or Windows file in an editor, this would also contain CR LF line ends. You can verify what is actually pasted using `xclip -o | hexdump -C`, where CR is `0d`, and LF is `0a`. On Linux, you should only see `0a` (that is, LF, not CR as I wrote mistakenly above). If you only see `0a` and still get two lines in the terminal, then something else is wrong.

Comment: From Ubuntu I copy 3 random terminal line, and I see only "0a":

Comment: 00000000  6d 6e 74 79 37 40 41 43  41 36 34 36 2d 6c 69 6e  |mnty7@ACA646-lin|
00000010  75 78 3a 7e 24 20 0a 6d  6e 74 79 37 40 41 43 41  |ux:~$ .mnty7@ACA|
00000020  36 34 36 2d 6c 69 6e 75  78 3a 7e 24 20 0a 6d 6e  |646-linux:~$ .mn|
00000030  74 79 37 40 41 43 41 36  34 36 2d 6c 69 6e 75 78  |ty7@ACA646-linux|
00000040  3a 7e 24                                          |:~$|
00000043

Comment: At this point, I think there's something wrong in pasting on x11-RDP session....

Answer (score 0):

Your stty output shows `-icrnl`  (do not translate carriage return to newline)

Try `stty icrnl`

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR: 'stty -icrnl' in ~/.bashrc fixed it for me under Arch linux

Under Arch linux with the "konsole|yakuake" terminal (xterm did *not* show the problem) I had the same problem.

My stty settings did not include "-icrnl".

-icrnl: Don't replace cariage return to new line.

So basically adding "stty -icrnl" to ~/.bashrc finally fixed the duplicate newline "bug" when pasting text in vim copied from Firefox before.

Basically this is a bug in Firefox or how it's using the corresponding GTK3 libs...